# How to use caching for SQL queries in groovy?

Tags: sql, caching, grails, groovy

I am creating global `groovy.sql.Sql` connection using existing DataSource shown in below code:

```
def checkConnection() {
    if (sql == null || sql.getConnection() == null) {
        sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    }
}
```

Here i am calling multiple methods to get different different data from database using this global SQL connection.

**Note**

My code is working fine when i am not using `sql.cacheStatements = true`. But when i am using `sql.cacheStatements = true` then it is closing my connection every time.

For every method firstly i am calling `checkConnection()` method.

```
def getCount() {
    checkConnection()
    sql.cacheStatements = true
    rows = sql.rows("select count(columnName) from tableName where date>= someValue and age>= someValue")
    return rows
}
```

***Question:*** How can i use caching concept for my statements using the groovy's `groovy.sql.Sql` connection.

Comment: Are you running your app under web server? Please provide details

Comment: Yes i am using tomcat 8 as web server and what types of details ?

Comment: In this case you have to manage statements caching on the level of data source in your tomcat. More, you can't have global connection. Tomcat closes them as web request finishes.